# Background-color property doesn't display on mobile

Tags: background-color

The title is probably self-explanatory, but when I load a page on desktop, the color shows up with the appropriate background-color.

However, loading that same URL on mobile, the background-color is not existent. Have any ideas why?

Comment: Can you paste your code please?

Comment: It is a very large and complicated project. URL is https://ethanmcfarlin.github.io